# Estrutura de banco de dados para sistema de enquete

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Tenho um projeto para desenvolver um sistema de enquete online. Estou preocupado na forma que eu vou buscar as respostas das questões para mostrar em um gráfico. Cada gráfico é cada questão a ser analisada. Vejamos, se eu possuo uma questão que possui 4 respostas diferentes, e que cada pergunta, somente pode ser marcado uma só resposta. Basicamente, a estrutura seria:

```
1) pergunta um
   a) questao um
   b) questao dois
   c) questao tres
   d) questao quatro
   e) questao cinco
2)
   a) questao um
   b) questao dois
   c) questao tres
```

Eu preciso de ajudar para definir qual o melhor critério para armazenar essas respostas no banco de dados. Basicamente, preciso saber quantas vezes na pergunta 1, a, b, c, d, e, foi selecionado para ser mostrado o gráfico da pergunta um. Se eu tivesse uma tabela na seguinda estrutura:

```
id_usuario 2
respostas ac
```

Nesse caso o usuário id 2, teria respondido a questão 1,letra a e questão 2, letra c. 
Mas a questão seria, se eu tratasse isso na programação seria muito trabalhoso para mim. Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de desenvolver esse sistema seguindo esses critérios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso você precisar configurar no banco (opcao_id, resposta_id, usuario_id) como um índice único ou tratar com PHP no momento da inserção.